# Use an operator defined in base class between derived class instances

Tags: c++

I have two classes, Base and Derived. Base defines an operator (here operator +) and I want to use it between instances of the Derived classes, but I can't manage to work this out.

Here's some minimal code explaining the problem :

```
class Base{
  public:
    Base(int X){ x = X; }

    Base operator+(const Base& rhs){
        return Base(x + rhs.x);
    }

    int x;
};

class Derived : public Base{
  public:
    using Base::Base;
};

int main(){
  Derived der1(0);
  Derived der2(0);

  Derived der3 = der1 + der2;

  return 0;
}
```

The compiler says :

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:21:23: error: conversion from ‘Base’ to non-scalar type ‘Derived’ requested
   Derived der3 = der1 + der2;
```

The Derived class doesn't need to have any attributes other than those inherited from Base.

Thanks!

Comment: You're calling it just fine - but it returns a Base, not a Derived. You could implement a new operator in Derived (probably calling the Base one). Or possibly you should be looking at the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern.

Comment: Well, the problem with implementing a new operator in Derived is that in the real code I have other Derived classes too. I'll take a look at that Curiously Recurring Template Pattern then, thanks :)

Comment: It works very well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common use case for the curriously recurring template pattern. An example would be

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int X) { x = X; }

    friend T operator+(const Base& lhs, const Base& rhs)
    {
        return T(lhs.x + rhs.x);
    }

    int x;
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public:
    Derived(int arg) : Base(arg) { }
    using Base::Base;
};

int main()
{
    Derived der1(1);
    Derived der2(2);

    Derived der3 = der1 + der2;

    return 0;
}
```

This would behave like [**so**](http://ideone.com/TkgmXT).

Friend name injection (or Barton Nackman trick) is used to generate a function upon instantiation of a templated type. The above is a rough sketch of what a design could be, but I should walk you through the process of calling the + operator.

1. `der1` and `der2` are converted to references to base class
2. The body of base's operator `+` is selected (even if it was in a different namespace, argument dependent lookup would kick in and we would have resolution)
3. The operator constructs a `T` which in this case has type `Derived` out of the sum

   ```
   (lhs.x + rhs.x)
   ```
4. That object is used to initialize `der3`